# I cannot re-create Gmail account

Tags: google-account, account-recovery

I have deleted my Gmail account because I wanted to have a dot inside but forgot to. Now it does not allow me to add new email with dot there because it recognizes the mail with dot as same as the deleted one.

Comment: It won't, because to Google with or without the dot is functionally the same (at least as far as Gmail goes). Google doesn't re-use user accounts, so you may be out of luck.

Comment: To expand: If your email address is RadkaPolákováBeránková@domain.com, and you tell people to email you at Radka.Poláková.Beránková@domain.com, it should still work.

Answer (score 3):

You *may* be able to recover your original deleted account if you do it shortly after deleting it.

> ### Recover a recently deleted Google Account
>
> If you [deleted your Google Account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32046), you have about 2–3 weeks to try to recover it. If your account is restored, you'll be able to sign in as usual to Gmail, Google Play, and other Google products.
>
> To try to recover your account:
>
> 1. Go to the [Account support page](https://accounts.google.com/signin/recovery).
> 2. Follow the instructions. You'll be asked some questions to confirm it's your account. Answer as best you can.
> 3. If your account is recovered, create a strong password that you haven't already used with this account. [Learn how to create a strong password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32040).

([source](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6236295))

Note that if you can't supply the right answers to their questions, they're not going to hand over the keys. (Sure, that's annoying, but imagine if someone *else* were trying to get your account. You'd want them to be very suspicious.)

If you can't recover the account, you'll have to create another. Google doesn't re-use usernames, so that name will be lost forever.